# Using Grunt to watch all files in my src directory and output to build

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-less, grunt-contrib-coffee

I'm completely new to Grunt and I want to use it in my next project.

What I want to do is, for example, to have the file at `src/server.coffee` to be compiled to `build/server.js` and the file at `src/public/assets/css/global.less` to be compiled to `build/public/assets/css/global.css`.

That means I want to keep the same file path after `src`, as well as the same name of every file, only changing its extension. I can do this manually for every file in my project but I'd really like Grunt to do this with every file in the `src` folder.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the answer in the docs -- I just didn't know how to look for it.

What I want to do is called *globbing*: setting global routines for the Gruntfile. It looks like this (in CoffeeScript):

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
    grunt.initConfig
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON "package.json"

        coffee:
            files:
                expand: true
                cwd: "src/"
                flatten: false
                src: ["**/*.coffee"]
                dest: "build/"
                ext: ".js"

        less:
            files:
                expand: true
                cwd: "src/"
                flatten: false
                src: ["**/*.less"]
                dest: "build/"
                ext: ".css"


    grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'
    grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-less'

    grunt.registerTask 'default', ['coffee', 'less'];

    return
```

`cwd` sets the base directory, `flatten: false` makes Grunt respect subdirectory structure and `[src: "**/*.coffee"]` makes it look for every `.coffee` file in every subdirectory of the `cwd`. The output goes to the `dest` folder.